# Making hamburger menu y-overflow: scroll when height exceeds vh

Tags: css, css-grid, hamburger-menu

I have a hamburger menu that displays when hovered over (when the site is less than 865px wide), but the issue I'm trying to work out right now is how to make the menu turn into a y-scroll when it overflows the vh, since it's position: sticky; you can notice when setting the page dimensions to be that of a mobile phone, that the hamburger menu overflows the vh, but I can't figure out how to get it to scroll when overflowing since its sticky.

Suggestions?

see code:

```
#header {
    display: grid;
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    grid-template-columns: 20% 80%;
    grid-template-rows: 50% 50%;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 7rem;
    z-index: 10;
    horizontal-overflow: hidden;
    background-color: black;
}
.headerLogo {
    grid-area: 1 / 1 / 3 / 2;
    align-self: center;
    margin-left: 1rem;
    height: 4.8rem;
}
#hamburger {
    align-self: center;
    justify-self: end;
    grid-area: 1 / 2 / 3 / 3;
    height: 3.25rem;
    padding: 2rem 1.5rem;
}
#header a:hover {
        color: lightgray;
}
#header a {
        text-decoration: none;
        color: white;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 865px) {

    /* Primary Larger Menu */
    #menu1 {
        grid-area: 2 / 2 / 3 / 3;
        justify-self: end;
        margin-top: 0.5rem;
        margin-right: 2.5rem;
        display: grid;
        grid-template-rows: 2rem 3rem;
        grid-template-columns: 5rem 5rem 7rem 6rem 5.5em 6rem;
        align-items: center;
        justify-items: center;
    }   
    .menu1 {
        padding-bottom: 1rem;
    }
    #mmObj1 {
    grid-area: 1 / 1 / 2 / 2;
    }
    #mmObj2 {
    grid-area: 1 / 2 / 2 / 3;
    }
    #mmObj3 {
    grid-area: 1 / 3 / 2 / 4;
    }
    #mmObj4 {
    grid-area: 1 / 4 / 2 / 5;
    }
    #mmObj5 {
    grid-area: 1 / 5 / 2 / 6;
    }
    #mmObj6 {
    grid-area: 1 / 6 / 2 / 7;
    }
    .dropdownGrid {
        align-self: start;
        display: grid;
        background-color: black;
        align-items: center;
        justify-items: center;
        visibility: hidden;
    }
    #techDropdown {
        grid-area: 2 / 3 / 3 / 4;
        width: 6.5rem;
        grid-template-columns: 6.5rem;
        grid-template-rows: 2.2rem 2.2rem 2.2rem 2.2rem;
    }
    #mmObj3:hover ~ #techDropdown {
        visibility: visible;
    }
    #techDropdown:hover {
        visibility: visible;
    }       
    #serviceDropdown {
        grid-area: 2 / 1 / 3 / 2;
        width: 11rem;
        grid-template-columns: 11rem;
        grid-template-rows: 2.2rem 2.2rem 2.2rem;
    }
    #mmObj1:hover ~ #serviceDropdown {
        visibility: visible;
    }
    #serviceDropdown:hover {
        visibility: visible;
    }
    #marketsDropdown {
        grid-area: 2 / 2 / 3 / 3;
        width: 12rem;
        grid-template-columns: 12rem;
        grid-template-rows: 2.2rem 2.2rem 2.2rem 2.2rem 2.2rem 2.2rem 2.2rem 2.2rem;
    }
    #mmObj2:hover ~ #marketsDropdown {
        visibility: visible;
    }
    #marketsDropdown:hover {
        visibility: visible;
    }   
    #hamburger {
        visibility: hidden;
    }
}

/* Secondary Smaller Menu Above Primary*/
.menu2 {
    grid-area: 1 / 2 / 2 / 3;
    justify-self: end;
    align-self: start;
    margin-top: 1rem;
    margin-right: 3rem;
    color: white;
}
.menu2 ul {
    margin: 0;
}
.menu2 li {
    font-size: 0.80rem;
    display: inline-block;
    padding-left: 0.5rem;
}
.menu2 p {
    font-size: 0.80rem;
}
.menu2 a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
}

/*mobile menu*/
@media only screen and (max-width: 865px) { 
    #mmObj1 {
        grid-area: 1 / 1 / 2 / 2;
    }
    #mmObj2 {
        grid-area: 3 / 1 / 3 / 2;
    }
    #mmObj3 {
        grid-area: 5 / 1 / 6 / 2;
    }
    #mmObj4 {
        grid-area: 7 / 1 / 8 / 2;
    }
    #mmObj5 {
        grid-area: 8 / 1 / 9 / 2;
    }
    #mmObj6 {
        grid-area: 9 / 1 / 10 / 2;
    }
    #menu1 {
        grid-area: 3 / 2 / 3 / 3;
        align-self: start;
        justify-self: end;
        display: grid;
        grid-template-rows: 2.5rem 6.5rem 2.5rem 15rem 2.5rem 8rem 2.5rem 2.5rem 2.5rem;
        grid-template-columns: 15rem;
        align-items: center;
        justify-items: end;
        background-color: black;
        visibility: hidden;
    }
    .menu1 {
        margin-right: 1.5rem;
        font-size: 1.25rem;
    }
    .dropdownGrid {
        display: grid;
        align-self: start;
        align-items: center;
        justify-items: end;
        margin-right: 1.5rem;
        grid-template-columns: 12rem;
    }
    #serviceDropdown {
        grid-area: 2 / 1 / 3 / 2;
        grid-template-columns: 15rem;
        grid-template-rows: 1.75rem 1.75rem 1.75rem;
    }
    #tsubObj1 {
        grid-area: 1 / 1 / 2 / 2;
    }
    #tsubObj2 {
        grid-area: 2 / 1 / 3 / 2;
    }
    #tsubObj3 {
        grid-area: 3 / 1 / 4 / 2;
    }
    #hamburger:hover ~ #menu1 {
        visibility: visible;
    }
    #menu1:hover {
        visibility: visible;
    }
    #serviceDropdown {
        grid-area: 2 / 1 / 3 / 2;
    }
    #marketsDropdown {      
        grid-area: 4 / 1 / 5 / 2;
        grid-template-rows: 1.75rem 1.75rem 1.75rem 1.75rem 1.75rem 1.75rem 1.75rem 1.75rem;
    }
    #techDropdown {
        grid-area: 6 / 1 / 7 / 2;
        grid-template-rows: 1.75rem 1.75rem 1.75rem 1.75rem;
    }
    .menu2 {
        visibility: hidden;
    }
}
```

```
<header id="header">
    <a class="headerLogo" href="index.html"><img class="headerLogo" src="content/logos/dig-500x-white.png" alt="logo"></a>
    <img id="hamburger" src="content/hamburger.svg">
    <nav id="menu1">
        <a class="menu1" id="mmObj1" href="#">###</a>
        <a class="menu1" id="mmObj2" href="#">###</a>
        <a class="menu1" id="mmObj3" href="#">###</a>
        <a class="menu1" id="mmObj4" href="#">Our Work</a>
        <a class="menu1" id="mmObj5" href="#">About Us</a>
        <a class="menu1" id="mmObj6" href="#">Contact Us</a>
        <nav class="dropdownGrid" id="techDropdown">
            <a class="serviceSub" id="ssubObj1" href="#">###</a>
            <a class="serviceSub" id="ssubObj2" href="#">###</a>
            <a class="serviceSub" id="ssubObj3" href="#">###</a>
            <a class="serviceSub" id="ssubObj4" href="#">###</a>
        </nav>
        <nav class="dropdownGrid" id="serviceDropdown">
            <a class="techSub" id="tsubObj1" href="#">###</a>
            <a class="techSub" id="tsubObj2" href="#">###</a>
            <a class="techSub" id="tsubObj3" href="#">###</a>
        </nav>
        <nav class="dropdownGrid" id="marketsDropdown">
            <a class="marketSub" id="msubObj1" href="#">Market 1</a>
            <a class="marketSub" id="msubObj2" href="#">Market 2</a>
            <a class="marketSub" id="msubObj3" href="#">Market 3</a>
            <a class="marketSub" id="msubObj4" href="#">Market 4</a>
            <a class="marketSub" id="msubObj5" href="#">Market 5</a>
            <a class="marketSub" id="msubObj6" href="#">Market 6</a>
            <a class="marketSub" id="msubObj7" href="#">Market 7</a>
            <a class="marketSub" id="msubObj8" href="#">Market 8</a>
        </nav>
    </nav>
    <nav class="menu2">
    <ul>
    <li> <a href="#">Blog</a> </li>
    <li> <p>|</p> </li>
    <li> <a href="#">Request a Quote</a> </li>
    <li> <p>|</p> </li>
    <li> <a href="#">Submit RFx</a> </li>
    <li> <p>|</p> </li>
    <li> <a href="#">24/7 Support: ###</a> </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

codepen: https://codepen.io/roomwillow/pen/VwmMPoJ

Answer (score 0):

You need to give a fixed-height to your `menu1` container inside the mobile media query and then apply an `overflow-y:scroll` to it. So your additional css for mobile view `menu1` will be something like :-

```
#menu1{
height:250px;
overflow-y:scroll;
}
```

Comment: the problem with this solution is that it assumes a fixed height for each viewport, which is a problem, because on screens taller than say.... 45rem, I want to not need to scroll, and to just display the entire menu, but on screens below 45rem in height, I want to have the menu fill as much of the page as possible, and to scroll only for the parts it cant fit, what I ended up doing was:

 `@media only screen and (max-height: 45rem) {
 #menu1 {
  height: 70vh;
  overflow-y: scroll;
 }`

which isn't perfect to what I wanted to do, but solves the issue for mobile devices